# MSI (Wix) to create directory, change permissions and copy files

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm struggling to get this working. They idea is to copy some files to ALLUSERSFOLDER in a directory created there which also needs it's permissions changed.

I have try using `<CreateFolder>, <util:PermissionEx> and <CopyFile>` but I only managed to get the folder created and its pemissions changed but not to copy (move) the files, here is the XML:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="MyApp">
            <Directory Id="PFSTORAGE" Name="storage"/>
      </Directory>             
</Directory>

<Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="ALLUSERSFOLDER" Name="MyApp"> 
                <Directory Id="AUSTORAGE" Name="storage"/>                    
           </Directory>

           <Component Id="AllUsersFiles" Guid="{F8765AB2-D78B-4A38-9FF4-DEEC1ACE6509}">
                <CreateFolder>
                    <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes"/>
                </CreateFolder>
                <CopyFile Id="copy" DestinationProperty="AUSTORAGE" SourceProperty="PFSTORAGE" SourceName="*.*" Delete="yes" />
                <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\MyApp\install">
                            <RegistryValue Value="installing" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
                 </RegistryKey>
            </Component>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Call this custom action once you have create the folder and changed permissions on the folder

```
<CustomAction Id="C_SetQtCmdLineMoveFiles" Property="QtExecCmdLine"
   Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /c move/Y &quot;[ALLUSERSFOLDER]storage\*.log&quot; &quot;[ALLUSERSFOLDER]NewFolder&quot;" />
<CustomAction Id="QtCmdMoveFiles" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="immediate" Return="ignore" />
```